# How / where do I place the “Await Task.Run()” here?

Tags: vb.net, async-await

With my program, a user can use the search function. This function “Suchen” (find) searches through  complete lists and returns a `List(Of Class_Post)`. This is then iterated through and `ListBox1` is filled with those members. That works fine but now I want to run the function `Suchen` asynchronously. Unfortunately, I can't do that. The current error is that `sortierte_Ergebnisse` (sorted_result) is used before a value is in it. Could you please help me with the syntax?

```
Private Sub Button_Suche_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Suche.Click
        Button_Reindrueck_Effekt(sender)
        If TextBox_Suche.Text = "" Then Return 
        Anzeigezustand = Anzeigezustaende.Es_wurde_gerade_die_Suchfunktion_betaetigt

        Dim sortierte_Ergebnisse As List(Of Class_Post) = Suchen(Text_in_Suchtextbox)
        If sortierte_Ergebnisse IsNot Nothing Then
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            For Each Posting As Class_Post In sortierte_Ergebnisse
                ListBox1.Items.Add(Posting.Ueberschrift & Tab & Tab & Posting.Erstelldatum_dieses_Posts)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

[image: current bug]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'd suggest that you wrap your `Suchen` method call in an async method and call `Task.Run` there:

```vb
Private Async Function SuchenAsync(text As String) As Task(Of List(Of Class_Post))
    Return Await Task.Run(Function() Suchen(text))
End Function
```

You can then make your event handler async too and call that async method:

```vb
Private Async Sub Button_Suche_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Suche.Click
    Button_Reindrueck_Effekt(sender)
    If TextBox_Suche.Text = "" Then Return
    Anzeigezustand = Anzeigezustaende.Es_wurde_gerade_die_Suchfunktion_betaetigt

    Dim sortierte_Ergebnisse = Await SuchenAsync(Text_in_Suchtextbox)
    If sortierte_Ergebnisse IsNot Nothing Then
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(sortierte_Ergebnisse.Select(Function(cp) $"{cp.Ueberschrift}{ControlChars.Tab}{ControlChars.Tab}{cp.Erstelldatum_dieses_Posts}").ToArray())
    End If
End Sub
```

Note the improved method of populating the `ListBox`, i.e. a single call to `AddRange` rather than calling `Add` in a loop.

I haven't tested that code but I'm pretty sure that it should work.

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney, it works that way. Thanks also for the improved ListBox filling.

Question: Does the wrapping of the ```Suchen``` method call and the ```Await Task.Run``` written in it have any particular effects?

Comment: @Daniel, wrapping the `Suchen` call in an awaited async method should mean that the UI won't be blocked while that method executes.

Comment: @Daniel I don't think it does anything more than you would get from doing it inline in the event handler.  The only potential benefit I can think of is that the on-exception behavior would be a little different for a function than a sub.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm aware of that. My question was heading in the direction if the "twice" await has another effect. Craig answered that. Thanks, both of you.

Comment: @Daniel, ah, I see. The extra method was more about the SRP than anything else. The search exists as a single method in the synchronous world so it's a good idea to maintain that in the asynchronous world. The event handler is then less cluttered.